# count occurences of string in substring with condition

Tags: vb.net, string, split, substring

I need to count how often a number is present in a string. it should count EVERY occurence with a whitespace in front, except those followed by a `=`.

For example: 
If i need to know how many "1" there are in this string: `this is a 1 ramdnom string with 2 numbers 1 with 1=something` it should return 2, as the third one is followed by an `=`

To find the occurrences I am using this:  `occurences = mystring.Split(" 1").Length - 1`

But how to exclude those followed by a `=`?

Thanks

Comment: Now, this is a situation where a `Regex` seems entirely appropriate.

Comment: yeah, i tought so, but how can i implement regex into this?

Comment: What if the last charachter in the string is a digit, does that count as an occurrence?

Comment: yes it counts.. everything that has a whitespace in front and NOT a equal sign after is valid. Thanks

Comment: Should this count or not: `1 =something`

Comment: `\W[0-9]([^=]|$)` seems to work

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it is valid. the = is not right after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like,

```
Dim occurrences = Regex.Matches(yourString, "\W[0-9]([^=]|$)").Count
```

---

If you'd like to do replacements, use a [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) overload.

---

Breaking it down, this expression matches

```
\W        // any whitespace character
[0-9]     // any deciaml digit
(         // either
[^=]      // not =
|         // or
$         // the end of the string
)
```

Comment: thanks! testing! can it be used to replace too? if for example i would like to replace every valid occurence of " 1" with " _"?

Comment: i would have to replace 0-9 with the number i want to check for, right? so if i want to know how many valid 1 there are i would have to replace 0-9 with 1...

Comment: @user2452250, I extended the answer.

Comment: @user2452250, `[0-9]` means any digit between `0` and `9` so, all decimal digits. If you want to match a single digit, say `1` the expression `\W1([^=]|$)` would suffice.

Comment: thanks! trying the replace, its more or less working so far. `nswapfirstpart = Regex.Replace(nswapfirstpart, "\W1([^=]|$)", " _")` problem is it is deleting the first character after the 1.

Comment: @user2452250 sounds like you want to do a partial replacement. Either, use the matches to pin point the parts of the string you want to alter or, If I were better with regexes I could probably use capture groups to pick out parts of the matches.

Comment: thanks for your help jodrell.. i will look into capture groups.